# Sign in user without creating multiple users in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

Using RSPEC and DEVISE, I'm able to sign in a `user` to run my tests. However, I've recently come across a problem with my method because using `before :each` is causing multiple users to be created, which causes my tests to break.

Should I change my method of testing? Or change my method of signing in a user?

**campaign_controller_spec.rb**

```
before :each do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  sign_in :user, @user
  @business = FactoryGirl.create(:business, user: @user)
end

describe "GET #index" do
  before :each do
    FactoryGirl.create(:active_campaign, business: @business)
    FactoryGirl.create(:inactive_campaign, business: @business)
  end

  it "no status or type filter" do
    get :index                                   #  <- LINE 22 OF ERROR
    expect(assigns(:campaigns).size).to eq 2
  end

  it 'status filter' do
    get :index, status: 'active'
    expect(assigns(:campaigns).size).to eq 1
  end
end
```

**campaigns_controller.rb**

```
def index
  # Get current user's campaigns
  @campaigns = current_user.business.campaigns

  # Filter by status (constraints are in routes)
  @campaigns = @campaigns.send(params[:status]) unless params[:status] == 'all'   #  <- LINE 7 OF ERROR
end
```

The problem is that all of the campaigns belong to the `business` with belong to USER-1 in the spec, but in the controller, the campaigns belong to another user (because several are being created) which doesn't have any campaigns associated.

The exact error is:

```
  1) CampaignsController [Signed in] GET #index no status or type filter
     Failure/Error: get :index
     TypeError:
       nil is not a symbol nor a string
     # ./app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb:7:in `index'
     # ./spec/controllers/campaigns_controller_spec.rb:22:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

*Small Update*

I DO have the `Database Cleaner` gem installed, which should clear the DB between tests. Here is the config (just in case it is incorrect):

```
#DatabaseCleaner
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `factory_girl` you'll want to use something like the `database_cleaner` gem to clean your database between tests. Check out:

https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#user-content-rspec-example

EDIT:

Realized that your error isn't caused by what you think it's caused. It's because you're doing a `.send(params[:status])` when `params[:status]` is nil because it's not passed in on the call to `get :index`... so once `.send(nil)` is invoked you get the stack trace.

Comment: Great suggestion, however, I already use the Database Cleaner gem. It's set to run between `:each` test. I too looked into this when this problem arose, but I double-checked the configuration and it looks alright. I'll add my Database Cleaner config to the main question, just in case.

Comment: The other, older, less-extensible way is to create all of your database fixtures prior to running your tests so that you aren't actually creating objects on the fly. However, this makes maintaining test data in a large codebase quite difficult.

Comment: @WesFoster: Edited my response with the actual error. Didn't bother reading the stack trace before. The answer in the edit is the real problem, not database cleaning.

Comment: You, my friend, are exactly correct. In my `routes.rb` I had set default values to the parameters (default to "all"). I assumed that this would eliminate the need to specify the missing params in the test. I added them in manually, and everything is passing!